# How to make use of string variables in a query in jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I have 2 string variables name and password. Now I have to use these variables in a query in where condition. How should I do it.
Suppose I want to execute a query-
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.name=name and student.pass=password"

I'm not able to do it. What is the right syntax for this query statement?

Comment: what you are using jdbc or hibernate framework for  database connection.?

Comment: 1. don't put such code in JSPs. JSPs are view components, supposed to generate HTML from objects stored into request attributes, and nothing else. Learn about MVC, and put the data access code into Java classes. 2. Learn JDBC. Google for Java JDBC tutorial. Specifically, learn about prepared statements.

Comment: @JBNizet, he may also learn hibernate too, depending on his needs and his environment...

Comment: @mr.mams the guy puts all its Java code in JSPs right now. Using Hibernate (or any other persistence technology) is premature. Start with the basics. Learn how to write Java classes first. Then learn the basics of persistence.

Comment: PreparedStatement is not working, only Statements are working in my program, What can be the problem? I have imported them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  following query:

SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.name='"+name+"' and student.pass='"+password+"'"

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM students WHERE students.name=? and student.pass=?");
st.setString(1, name);
st.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation, and include proper resource management. Your code is leaking statement and result set.